# Assigning a result based on range of values

Tags: excel, vba

This code is in Excel VBA, trying to attain a letter final grade. But errors occur during the conditions.

```
Sub A()

Dim GetLetterGrade As Double
Dim Score As Double
Select Case Score
    Case Is >= 85
            GetLetterGrade = "A"
        Case Is < 85 >= 70
            GetLetterGrade = "B"
    Case Is < 70 >= 60
            GetLetterGrade = "C"
        Case Is < 60 >= 50
            GetLetterGrade = "D"
    Case Is < 50
            GetLetterGrade = "F"
End Select

Range("H17").Value = GetLetterGrade

End Sub
```

Comment: `Case Is < 85 >= 70` <-- I haven't used VBA in years, but I'm pretty sure that's invalid syntax.

Comment: `Case 70 To 85` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement

Comment: I've not used VBA but maybe you're missing boolean operators

example: `Is < 85 >= 70` becomes `Is < 85 And Is >= 70`

boolean operators: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/boolean-expressions

Comment: Also, `GetLetterGrade` needs to be a `String` and you never assign a value to `Score`. You only need to test the values in descending order since `Select Case` will stop at the first true one.

Comment: I would do this on the sheet with vlookup or index with match then paste special values.

Answer (score 1):

You declare `GetLetterGrade` as `Double` but you assign letter to it, change it to `String`.

`Score` is declared but not assigned, I assume you have the score in cell `A1`.

What you want could be written like this, `Select` statement will pick the first expression that fulfills the test expression so the values can be tested in descending order:

```
Option Explicit

Sub A()

    Dim GetLetterGrade As String
    Dim Score As Double
    Score = Cells(1, 1).Value
    
    Select Case Score        
        Case Is >= 85:  GetLetterGrade = "A"
        Case Is >= 70:  GetLetterGrade = "B"
        Case Is >= 60:  GetLetterGrade = "C"
        Case Is >= 50:  GetLetterGrade = "D"
        Case Else:      GetLetterGrade = "F"
    End Select
    
    Range("H17").Value = GetLetterGrade
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using a Function in Excel or VBA

- You could write a function. Copy it to a standard module, e.g. `Module1`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Function GetLetterGrade( _
    ByVal Score As Variant) _
As String

    If Not IsNumeric(Score) Then Exit Function
    
    Select Case Score
        Case Is >= 85: GetLetterGrade = "A"
        Case Is >= 70: GetLetterGrade = "B"
        Case Is >= 60: GetLetterGrade = "C"
        Case Is >= 50: GetLetterGrade = "D"
        Case Else: GetLetterGrade = "F"
    End Select
    
End Function
```

- Then you could use it in Excel, to get the letter grade from e.g. cell `G17`, by using the following formula in e.g. cell `H17`:

  ```
  =GetLetterGrade(G17)
  ```
- In VBA, you could utilize the function in the following simplified way:

```vb
Sub GetLetterGradeTEST()
    
    Const srgAddress As String = "G2:G21"
    Const dCol As String = "H"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' be more specific
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range(srgAddress)
    
    Dim sCell As Range

    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        sCell.EntireRow.Columns(dCol).Value = GetLetterGrade(sCell.Value)
    Next sCell
    
    MsgBox "Letter grades populated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```